# Stuck on a screen asking me to connect my controller

Tags: ps3

So I bought a PS3 and played a game yesterday. Today the screen is stuck on a black screen that says "connect the controller using a USB cable, then press the PS button". I have a wireless controller, so what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Sounds like your controller got unsynced somehow.  Do you have a USB cord to connect it to your PS3?

Comment: It's wireless , it takes batteries no cord.

Comment: @Chris is this a 2nd hand PS3 with 3rd party controllers? the stock standard PS3 controlers that one come with a PS3 or Sony ones come with USB Cables and the batteries can not be removed unless you pull apart the controller

Comment: Until we know which controller it is, we can't help.

Answer (score 6):

Your wireless controller is probably completely discharged. So, when you are trying to use it, it can't do anything as there is no more energy in it.

When you bought your PS3, you probably got a USB cord in the box which looks like [this](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41WCZ5Q9LTL.jpg). Connect it (the left one on the picture) to your PS3, and then to your PS3 controller (the right one on the picture). Then push the PS button. You should then see that the controller is being lighted up, and you should be able to interact with your PS3 and leave that screen.

Linking the controller to the PS3 with this cable will recharge the controller. If you let it connected for a bit and then disconnect it again, you should be able to play and keep interacting with your PS3 again without using the cable. But you do need to recharge it from times to times. A PS3 controller takes between 1 and 2 hours to fully recharge.